# how to do second request with if statement within a observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, concatenation

**The goal**

I want to execute one http request and also want to do a other http request that is based on a if statement. The observer need to do a emit when:

1. firstvar and secondvar are equal and only 1 http request is executed
2. firstvar and secondvar are not equal and 2 http request are executed

**This is some pseudo code that I have**

```
class ApiCallClass {
  methodThatReturnsObservable: Observable<{}> {
   observable = this.http.get(firstUrl);
   if (firstvar !== secondvar) {
     observable.concat(this.http.get(secondUrl);
   }
   return observable;
  }
}
```

**Questions**

We noticed that the second request is aborting. Is this something because of using concat and returning the observable?

Do I use the concat method correctly?

Comment: it works now, thx to JB Nizet and a little more research. if statement was wrong and didn't return the new observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat()` **returns** a new Observable. It doesn't mutate the original one.

So you need

```
observable = observable.concat(this.http.get(secondUrl);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, but thanks for your addition :) changed the code based on your answer

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What are your inputs, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?